# What does "Show Group Colors" do?

Tags: graph-editor, dopesheet

This toggle locates at View menu on both Dopesheet and Graph Editor. There is few information about it, and I can hardly understand the tooltip. I wonder what the "Show Group Colors" toggle does, or how it affects.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It displays the bone names background on the left in the *Color Set* select in the *Bone Groups* 
settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently it is (afaics) only used for bone groups.

But this feature may evolve in future, those colors are actually those of the **action groups** (i.e. a set of actions). It just happens that currently, they are only set when matching a bone group…